# How to convert varchar to Integer sybase?

Tags: sql, int, sybase, type-conversion, varchar

I can't cast or convert my varchar data , for example I have a varchar 145.345
and I want to convert it to Int , how can I do it? I can't do it directly because that number is taken from a gps so the format is not number.

Comment: What have you tried? And given that 145.345 isn't an integer, what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: Int can not have decimal.  You can convert it to 145 but not 145.345 because 145.345 is not an int.  You can convert it to a numeric or decimal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My solution was: from that number (for example 123.456) I extracted 123 as varchar, then I extracted 456 as an another varchar. After that, I concatenated those 2 varchars and finally converted it into an Int (or any other format, as desired).

Thanks for your help, guys.

Comment: I am sorry but the down-vote is because despite it is accepted answer, it does not answer the post "how to convert to int". Either you omitted some vital piece of information from question/answer (e.g. 123.456 should become 123456), or needed converting into decimal. Anyway, this is not answer to original question. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `select cast( value as int )` but it may fail because 145.345 isn't an integer. If it's always going to be numeric and you want to truncate it to an integer, you could use `select cast( cast( value as float ) as int )`.

Comment: My choice was: cut that number for example 123.456 , I extracted 123 as varchar , then I extracted 456 as varchar,after that, concat those 2 expressions and finally convert it into Int or any format.